# Why isn't Valgrind Working?

Tags: c, ubuntu, valgrind

I'm new to C, Ubuntu and decided to install Valgrind and test it on this simple C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *p;

int main(void) {
    p = calloc(100, sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

I've placed this code inside sum.c file and compiled it. Then I've typed:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes sum
```

in the terminal window and this is what I got:

[image]

I don't know if it keep looping or just get stuck, but it would stay this way until I click ctrl+d to stop it and this is what I get:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong ? Why can't I see that I've got a memory leak ?

By the way, this is Ubuntu version 11.04.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why post screenshots?  It's just plain text.  Cut and paste is fine.

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` for `calloc`.

Comment: Yeah, It's a trouble for me to cut and paste since I run Ubuntu on VirtualBox and the internet connection in VM is damn slow so I posted this question from windows

Comment: @Robert777 I use VirtualBox all the time (and currently have 3 VM's on my desktop) and I can cut and past text between the VM's and the host

Comment: @PeterM Thanks for letting me know that it's possible, I'll try google it and find out how it's done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice the

```
00000     0
```

You're running **`/usr/bin/sum` instead of your own executable**, because you didn't say `./sum`. That's why you have to hit `C-d`: `sum(1)` waits until EOF.

---

As a side note, it's highly likely you won't get a leak reported, but rather a "memory still reachable".

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works, and it did show me that there is still memory reachable :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use the following notation

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./sum
```

That is if 'sum' is the name of your executable. Notice the addition of `'./'`